# Race condition when fetching request.url in Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node webapp which supports URLs in multiple languages. I have some middleware to generate a Welsh version of the current URL (eg. for the URL `/foo`, the Welsh version would be `/welsh/foo`), which is presented on-page as a link.

This function takes a `request` object and returns the updated URL (accessed via `request.url`). Unfortunately, when I open several pages at once on my site, some pages get the wrong URL in the `<a>` link (eg. they get the Welsh URL for one of the other pages I've opened). If I reload the page, the link is re-generated, this time correctly.

My middleware looks like this:

```
res.locals.getCurrentUrl = (req, locale) => {
    // snip: some logic to check if the URL already contains the locale
    return "://" + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
};
```

... then I call it in templates like `getCurrentUrl(request, 'welsh')`.

I only see this behaviour when I open a dozen tabs at once (via JavaScript – I have a status page with a button that opens a bunch of site URLs at once). Obviously this isn't a real-life use case, but at moments of high traffic, this race condition might kick in.

Is there a better, more reliable way here to associate per-request variables like `url` with the rendered output? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by making the `request` object available to my templates in a middleware function (beforehand I set it as a global on the template engine which clearly introduced this race condition):

```
app.use(path, (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.request = req;
    return next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you're using a Lambda function, and those retain the outer scope.

Try

```
res.locals.getCurrentUrl = function() {...}
```

instead.

Comment: Tried this – no joy.

Comment: OK.  Was worth a try.  I guess you've got a global variable somewhere, then.  Make sure you're initializing all of your variables and declare them as close to use as possible.  Good luck with it.